# Jordan Canonical Form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine the Jordan canonical form of the matrix: $\quad\begin{bmatrix} -7 & 9 \\ -4 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you done any of the work and can share that? Is there a particular point you are getting stuck? Did you find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints, to find the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), we can use the following approach (and others are possible too):

- (1) Find the eigenvalues (we have a multiplicity $2$ eigenvalue $\lambda_{1,2} = -1$)
- (2) Find the eigenvectors (we find one eigenvector and a second generalized eigenvector)
- (3) Write $A = P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1}$, where $J$ is the Jordan block (eigenvalues) and P is the corresponding eigenvectors.

**Updates**

To find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors, we set up and solve the characteristic polynomial $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, so we get ($v_i's$ are the eigenvectors):

- $\lambda_1 = -1, ~v_1 = (3, 2)$
- $\lambda_2 = -1, ~v_2 = (-\dfrac{1}{2}, 0)$

**Jordan Form**

The JF is given by:

$$A = PJP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}3 & -1/2\\2 & 0\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1/2\\-2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Note what makes up $J$ and the columns of $P$.

Comment: Nicely put + (xtra characters)

Comment: Thanks! I'm teaching myself Jordan form for an exam, so I am rather shaky with it at the moment. I found an eigenvector of $\lambda=-1$ with multiplicity 2, with corresponding eigenvectors $[1\ 2/3]^{T}$ and $[3/2\ 1]^{T}$ (which I don't think is correct...).

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.

Comment: @KirkFogg: You are very welcome. Please note that the eigenvectors are not unique, but using RREF (Gaussian Elimination), you should be able to derive the ones I showed. Also, for the second eigenvector, we setup and solve $[A]\lambda I]v_2 = v_1$, to find a generalized eigenvector. Give a whirl!

Comment: Oh, I bet! There is so many ways kids (and anyone) can be taken advantage of, or make grievous choices...with all their online social networking.